# is electrical insulated hand glove enough for household electrical work

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, circuit-breaker, safety

The circuit breaker panel cover is metal so it might shock if one of the wires inside get damaged and it might come in contact with the panel cover.

The use case is when one of the tripper goes off , we might have to open the panel to turn in back on.

So just want to be careful.

So If I wear just a electrically insulated hand glove , am I safe or I have to buy a pair of Electrical hazard footwear or just a rubber footwear ?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can only speak about the US, which this photo does not seem to be, but : The case should be grounded, so it should never have significant voltage on it even if a wire did somehow get loose.

And wires should never get loose if you haven't been tampering with them. This *shouldn't* require protection unless you dismount the front panel -- and if you're doing that you need more knowledge than this question suggests you have. (And in that case you should have turned off power "upstream" of the breaker box before opening it).

Unless there's something you haven't told us, I don't think you need any protection just to operate a circuit breaker.

Comment: The breaker panel is not grounded ,When I enquired , my electrician simply brushed it off saying that's nothing to be bothered about.. I don't know why .. may be he has no ground supply line ? or may be he's right . I'm just suspecting human error ? So I just want to be bit more careful

Comment: "It's nothing to be bothered about" is not "no". In the US, it would have to be grounded. Dunno about your local codes.